# Jquery SpellChecker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for Jquery SpellChecker Plug in if any body knows where I can find SpellCheker.js file please help me out..

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker

I didn't see any other branches with source code. The author's email is in the source, so you can ask him for more information.

Comment: I am the author of this plugin. I have recently put a lot of work into rewriting this plugin. You can find the updated version here: https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker

Comment: @badsyntax this is why I like stackoverflow, thank you.

Comment: do you mind updating the link to point to the new version?

Answer (score 3):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AtD

Comment: This one is great and so easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

Hiya.  I was looking for one as well... ended up modifying an older non-jQuery one named "spellerpages" to be jQuery integrated.  The resulting project is now available here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jspeller